# Group Data on elastic search with same value on two key

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I have just started to learn about elastic search and facing a problem on group aggregation.  I have a data set on elastic search like  :

```
[{
    srcIP : "10.0.11.12",
    dstIP : "19.67.78.91",
    totalMB : "0.25"
},{
    srcIP : "10.45.11.62",
    dstIP : "19.67.78.91",
    totalMB : "0.50"
},{
    srcIP : "13.67.52.91",
    dstIP : "10.0.11.12",
    totalMB : "0.75"
},{
    srcIP : "10.23.64.12",
    dstIP : "10.45.11.62",
    totalMB : "0.25"
}]
```

I Just want to group data on the basis of **srcIP** and sum the field **totalMB** but I just wanna add up on more thing like when group by performing on scrIP then it will match the **srcIP** value to **dstIP** value and also sum the **totalMB** for **dstIP**.

Output should be like this :

```
buckets : [{
    key : "10.0.11.12",
    total_GB_SrcIp :{
        value : "0.25"
    },
    total_GB_dstIP :{
        value : "0.75"
    }
},
{
    key : "10.45.11.62",
    total_MB_SrcIp :{
        value : "0.50"
    },
    total_MB_dstIP :{
        value : "0.25"
    }
}]
```

I have done normal aggregation for one key but didn't get the final query for my problem. 
Query :

```
GET /index*/_search
{
    size : 0,
    "aggs": {
        "group_by_srcIP": {
          "terms": {
        "field": "srcIP",
        "size": 100,
        "order": {
          "total_MB_SrcIp": "desc"
        }
          },
          "aggs": {
        "total_MB_SrcIp": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "TotalMB"
          }
        }
          }
    }
  }
}
```

Hope you understand my problem on the basis of sample output.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can simply add a second aggregation called `group_by_dstIP` on field `dstIP`. Granted you won't have the src/dst total fields in the same bucket, but your client application can easily do it.

Comment: @Val : yeah, I had done this way also but I have thousands of different IP and i need to know which IP value that is same in srcIP and dstIP have topmost uses of Data. I thought looping on the data is the last option if I can do by query its best.

Comment: Another way of looking at this is to use the [Graph Explore API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/graph-explore-api.html), where edges are IP addresses and vertices are number of bytes.

Answer (score 3):

As per my understanding, you need a sum aggregation on field (totalMB) with respect to distinct values in two another fields (srcIP, dstIP).

AFAIK, elastic search is not that good for aggregating on values of multiple fields, unless you combine those fields together using some document [ingestion](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.3/ingest.html) or combine it on application side itself. (I may be wrong here, though).

I gave it a try to get required output using [scripted_metric](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html) aggregation. (Please read about it if you don't know what it is or how it works)

I experimented on painless script to do following in aggregation:

1. pick srcIp, dstIp & totalMB from each doc
2. populate a cross-mapping like IP -> { (src : totalMBs), (dst : totalMBs) } in a map
3. return this map as result of aggregation

Here is the actual search query with aggregation:

```
GET /testIndex/testType/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "ip-addr": {
      "scripted_metric": {
        "init_script": "params._agg.addrs = []",
        "map_script": "def lst = []; lst.add(doc.srcIP.value); lst.add(doc.dstIP.value); lst.add(doc.totalMB.value); params._agg.addrs.add(lst);",
        "combine_script": "Map ipMap = new HashMap(); for(entry in params._agg.addrs) { def srcIp = entry.get(0); def dstIp = entry.get(1); def mbs = entry.get(2); if(ipMap.containsKey(srcIp)) {def srcMbSum = mbs + ipMap.get(srcIp).get('srcMB'); ipMap.get(srcIp).put('srcMB',srcMbSum); } else {Map types = new HashMap(); types.put('srcMB', mbs); types.put('dstMB', 0.0); ipMap.put(srcIp, types); } if(ipMap.containsKey(dstIp)) {def dstMbSum = mbs + ipMap.get(dstIp).get('dstMB'); ipMap.get(dstIp).put('dstMB',dstMbSum); } else {Map types = new HashMap(); types.put('srcMB', 0.0); types.put('dstMB', mbs); ipMap.put(dstIp, types); } } return ipMap;",
        "reduce_script": "Map resultMap = new HashMap(); for(ipMap in params._aggs) {for(entry in ipMap.entrySet()) {def ip = entry.getKey(); def srcDestMap = entry.getValue(); if(resultMap.containsKey(ip)) {Map types = new HashMap(); types.put('srcMB', srcDestMap.get('srcMB') + resultMap.get(ip).get('srcMB')); types.put('dstMB', srcDestMap.get('dstMB') + resultMap.get(ip).get('dstMB')); resultMap.put(ip, types); } else {resultMap.put(ip, srcDestMap); } } } return resultMap;"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here are experiment details:

**Index mapping:**

```
GET testIndex/_mapping
{
  "testIndex": {
    "mappings": {
      "testType": {
        "dynamic": "true",
        "_all": {
          "enabled": false
        },
        "properties": {
          "dstIP": {
            "type": "ip"
          },
          "srcIP": {
            "type": "ip"
          },
          "totalMB": {
            "type": "double"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Sample input:**

```
POST testIndex/testType
{
    "srcIP" : "10.0.11.12",
    "dstIP" : "19.67.78.91",
    "totalMB" : "0.25"
}

POST testIndex/testType
{
    "srcIP" : "10.45.11.62",
    "dstIP" : "19.67.78.91",
    "totalMB" : "0.50"
}

POST testIndex/testType
{
    "srcIP" : "13.67.52.91",
    "dstIP" : "10.0.11.12",
    "totalMB" : "0.75"
}

POST testIndex/testType
{
    "srcIP" : "10.23.64.12",
    "dstIP" : "10.45.11.62",
    "totalMB" : "0.25"
}
```

**Query output:**

```
{
  "took": 3,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 4,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "ip-addr": {
      "value": {
        "13.67.52.91": {
          "srcMB": 0.75,
          "dstMB": 0
        },
        "10.23.64.12": {
          "srcMB": 0.25,
          "dstMB": 0
        },
        "10.45.11.62": {
          "srcMB": 0.5,
          "dstMB": 0.25
        },
        "19.67.78.91": {
          "srcMB": 0,
          "dstMB": 0.75
        },
        "10.0.11.12": {
          "srcMB": 0.25,
          "dstMB": 0.75
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

Here is **readable query** for better understanding.

```
"scripted_metric": {
  "init_script": "params._agg.addrs = []",
  "map_script": """
      def lst = [];
      lst.add(doc.srcIP.value);
      lst.add(doc.dstIP.value);
      lst.add(doc.totalMB.value);
      params._agg.addrs.add(lst);
    """,
  "combine_script": """
      Map ipMap = new HashMap();
      for(entry in params._agg.addrs) { 
        def srcIp = entry.get(0);
        def dstIp = entry.get(1);
        def mbs = entry.get(2);

        if(ipMap.containsKey(srcIp)) { 
          def srcMbSum = mbs + ipMap.get(srcIp).get('srcMB');
          ipMap.get(srcIp).put('srcMB',srcMbSum);
        } else {
          Map types = new HashMap();
          types.put('srcMB', mbs);
          types.put('dstMB', 0.0);
          ipMap.put(srcIp, types);
        }

        if(ipMap.containsKey(dstIp)) {
          def dstMbSum = mbs + ipMap.get(dstIp).get('dstMB');
          ipMap.get(dstIp).put('dstMB',dstMbSum);
        } else {
          Map types = new HashMap();
          types.put('srcMB', 0.0);
          types.put('dstMB', mbs);
          ipMap.put(dstIp, types);
        }
      }
      return ipMap;
    """,
  "reduce_script": """
      Map resultMap = new HashMap();
      for(ipMap in params._aggs) {
        for(entry in ipMap.entrySet()) {
          def ip = entry.getKey();
          def srcDestMap = entry.getValue();

          if(resultMap.containsKey(ip)) {
            Map types = new HashMap();
            types.put('srcMB', srcDestMap.get('srcMB') + resultMap.get(ip).get('srcMB'));
            types.put('dstMB', srcDestMap.get('dstMB') + resultMap.get(ip).get('dstMB'));
            resultMap.put(ip, types);
          } else {
            resultMap.put(ip, srcDestMap);
          } 
        } 
      }
      return resultMap;
    """
}
```

However, prior to going in depth, I would suggest you to test it out on some sample data and check if it works. Scripted metric aggregations do have considerable impact on query performance.

One more thing, to get required key string in aggregation result, replace all occurrences of 'srcMB' & 'dstMB' in script to '**total_GB_SrcIp**' & '**total_GB_DstIp**' as per your need.

Hope this may help you or some one.

FYI, I tested this on ES v5.6.11.

Comment: Thanks manoj for your effort but If there will be large set of data it throwing timeout error and what will be the changes if i need only top 5 IP whose srcMB and dstMB value is largest?

Comment: @shiva You are getting timeout error because your existing ES infrastructure (shards, data nodes) is not able to do the processing for large data. The above mentioned script can be further optimized as per requirement. If you look at script, its simple java. You would need to rethink on how this can be improved. Few areas can be: using TreeMap to store entries w.r.t descending order of MBs; or using different data structure altogether; try `return params._aggs;` in reduce script, and see if you get output; you can distribute processing on ES side and on client application as well.